# How do i parse an XML file with multiple node in JAVA using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have and xml from a webservice but even if the structure is standard i have some problem parsing this file with JAVA Spring using JAXB, The structure it's something like this:

```xml
           <organisation>
              <organisation>
                 <organisationIdentification>
                    <uid> 
                       <uidOrganisationIdCategorie>123</uidOrganisationIdCategorie>
                       <uidOrganisationId>1234531234</uidOrganisationId>
                    </uid>                                          
                    <OtherOrganisationId>
                       <organisationIdCategory></organisationIdCategory>
                       <organisationId></organisationId>
                    </OtherOrganisationId>
                    <OtherOrganisationId >
                       <organisationIdCategory></organisationIdCategory>
                       <organisationId></organisationId>
                    </OtherOrganisationId>
                    <organisationName>Orgnanisation name</organisationName>
                    <organisationLegalName">Name SA</organisationLegalName>
                    <legalForm >3698</legalForm>
                 </organisationIdentification>
                 <nogaCode>123456</nogaCode>
                 <contact>
                    <address>
                       <otherAddressCategory>main</otherAddressCategory>
                       <postalAddress>
                          <organisation >
                             <organisationName>Name SA</organisationName>
                          </organisation>
                          <addressInformation>
                             <street/>
                             <town></town>
                             <zipCode></zipCode>
                             <country>
                                <countryIdISO2></countryIdISO2>
                                <countryNameShort></countryNameShort>
                             </country>
                          </addressInformation>
                       </postalAddress>
                    </address>
                    <address>
                       <otherAddressCategory></otherAddressCategory>
                       <postalAddress>
                          <organisation>
                             <organisationName>-</organisationName>
                          </organisation>
                          <addressInformation>
                             <street></street>
                             <town></town>
                             <zipCode></zipCode>
                             <country>
                                <countryIdISO2></countryIdISO2>
                                <countryNameShort></countryNameShort>
                             </country>
                          </addressInformation>
                       </postalAddress>
                    </address>
                    <address>
                       <otherAddressCategory>postbox</otherAddressCategory>
                       <postalAddress>
                          <organisation>
                             <organisationName>-</organisationName>
                          </organisation>
                          <addressInformation>
                             <street/>
                             <postOfficeBoxNumber></postOfficeBoxNumber>
                             <postOfficeBoxText/>
                             <town/>
                             <zipCode></zipCode>
                             <country>
                                <countryIdISO2></countryIdISO2>
                                <countryNameShort></countryNameShort>
                             </country>
                          </addressInformation>
                       </postalAddress>
                    </address>
                    <email>
                       <emailAddress>info@mail.ch</emailAddress>
                    </email>
                    <internet>
                       <internetAddress>http://www.site.ch</internetAddress>
                    </internet>
                 </contact>
                 <languageOfCorrespondance>IT</languageOfCorrespondance>
              </organisation>
              <uidregInformation>
                 <uidregSource>
                    <uidOrganisationIdCategorie></uidOrganisationIdCategorie>
                    <uidOrganisationId >11111111</uidOrganisationId>
                 </uidregSource>
                 <uidregSource>
                    <uidOrganisationIdCategorie>CHE</uidOrganisationIdCategorie>
                    <uidOrganisationId>23232111</uidOrganisationId>
                 </uidregSource>
                 <uidregSource>

              </uidregInformation>

           </organisation>
```

It's possible with JAXB parsing this file into a class model and keep all the value from the multiple nodes (uidOrganisationId / town / zipCode).
I don't know how to store the values ​​where there are same nodes.

Comment: Could you post the code of your JAXB-annotated class? Do you have an XML Schema for the XML data?

Comment: with multiple nodes of same type <Nodes><node></node><node></node></Nodes> use list

Comment: and if you're about address appearing in different sub-nodes -> create sub class, that will map address and insert it in main class where needed, creating nested description